# Mounted hook running before Created data api is finished loading

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to load a function when images from a data api are finished loading. However, it looks like the function is run before the ApiService is finished and thus the `TiffParser.replaceIMG()` function is not working properly

Here's my setup:

```
data: function() {
    return {
      images: null,
      imageLink: apiService.imgSrc,
      loading: true,
      errored: false
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    // fetch the data when the view is created and the data is
    // already being observed
    apiService
      .getImages(this.$route.params.id)
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.errored = true;
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.images = response.data;
      });
  },
  //vue js provides us `mounted()`. This means `onload` in javascript
  mounted: function() {
    TiffParser.replaceIMG();
  }
```

Is `mounted` the correct lifecycle hook for this task?

Comment: The component isn't aware it has to wait for the response, so no Mounted is not a good place for that call. The most obvious place is inside the `.then()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [`watcher`](https://it.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) for your `images`.

```
created() {
  const unwatch = this.$watch('images', function(newValue = [], oldValue = []) {
    // any code here will execulte once the value of `images` changes
    TiffParser.replaceIMG();

    unwatch(); // remove the watcher

    // Note that you cannot use ES6 arrow functions here, since arrow functions 
    // are bound to the parent context, and the `this` keyword
    // would then not be bound correctly to the Vue instance.
  });

  // fetch images
}
```

> Is mounted the correct lifecycle hook for this task?

Yes, if you need to access or modify the DOM of your component immediately before or after the initial render.

However, `images` would be empty when it's first mounted so using a `watcher` instead of the `mounted` hook seems more appropriate for this use case.